# Moving a grails project to use greclipse

Tags: eclipse, grails

We have been using GGTS for our grails projects.  But we have a simple grails 2.4 project that we would like to move to AWS.  Our preference is to use the latest Eclipse and AWS SDK for java directly (and not use the grails aws plugin). We have downloaded and installed the greclipse plugin.

We are in the process of setting it up, but it looks promising.  However, I was surprised by this line that I saw in the greclipse installation instructions:

```
Start with a compatible version of Eclipse (available from 
http://eclipse.org/downloads). Since Groovy-Eclipse relies on Eclipse's Java 
tooling (the JDT), almost any flavor of Eclipse that includes the JDT will 
be compatible. This includes the Java IDE, Classic, RCP, JavaEE, etc. 
Flavors such as Eclipse for PHP developers are not compatible because it 
does not include the JDT. If you are interested in Grails tooling, then you 
must install the Groovy/Grails Tool Suite.
```

What additional tooling is provided by the GGTS grails tooling that is not in greclipse groovy tooling?  Has anyone else gone this route?   If so, suggestions for configuration?

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm answering my own question:  I had forgotten that grails and groovy are not synonymous, since they are interchangeable for so many purposes.  But grails is a framework that uses the groovy scripting language.  So the missing grails tooling is quite significant:  it is what allows one to create a grails application.